# Protect file in web root but give access from php

Tags: php

I have a situation where I want to protect a file from public access, but enable read and write from php. The file contains sensitive information like passwords.

The problem is that

- I cannot put the file outside the web root (server security restriction on access from php)
- I would like to avoid `mysql` database.

Also I would try to avoid `.htacess` files.

So if I make a folder, say `private`, in the web root, and do

```
chmod 700 private
```

Then, if the file to protect is `private/data`, I do

```
chmod 700 private/file
```

will this be a safe setup? So now I can read and write to the file from `php` but it is not accessible for the public?

Is this a safe setup?

Comment: If this is something like a config file, you shouldn't allow writing to it from PHP at all. That's the kind of thing you store in a temp file or DB somewhere after it has been sanitized.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to place this file outside of the webroot. If you can't go outside of the webroot because of some other security measure you need to slap someone because this is actually making your application _less_ secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP runs as the same user as the webserver so if PHP can read it, so can your webserver (and vice versa).

If you don't want to use `.htaccess` there is another trick: save the file as a `.php` file. Even if someone accesses the file from the web they can't see the source, they might just get a white page or maybe an error depending on what exactly is in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you not just download that `.php` file with `curl` or maybe `curl` is running under another user?

Comment: If you access the file through the webserver it will give you the output, not the source.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running suPHP or fastCGI php, you can use a setup similar to what you've described to limit access to files.  Otherwise, PHP will use the same user as the web server, and any file PHP can access is also accessible via url.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but I am not sure I understand how this file can be accessible via URL.. It means in practice that any file permissions in the webroot is neglected? So all files in webroot are accessible for anyone regardsless of file permissions?

Comment: No - file permissions are used in the context of whatever user the web server process is running as.  In a typical PHP setup, the php user is  the same as the web server user.  So, if the file accessible for php, it will also be accessible for the web server - which means you can access the file via its path relative to the web root.

Answer (score 1):

If want to keep the restrictions stipulated (which are rather strange), and as (i guess) you do not wish/have access to apache config directives, consider adding PHP to some group and give the group only rights to the file, ie. apache cannot read (if its not in root/wheel).

Or make it a valid .php file (so only php would be invoker when the file is requested) which returns nothing or redirects when invoked with php. or just cipher it.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a good idea. So how do I now that php will belong to a given group?